# Help me understand voltage X

Tags: voltage, diodes, rectifier

I am trying to understand an explanation written here: http://people.ucalgary.ca/~aknigh/vsd/ssim/vsi/co.html

As far as I understand:

- voltage V(A) is line 1 voltage
- voltage V(B) is line 2 voltage

... but what/where is voltage V(X) ... or V(X) at time t? I would like to understand the equation "Once phase B voltage is high enough for its diode to conduct:".

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you're asking a question about a particular circuit, then that circuit should be here in your question, not linked somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Va and Vb refer to the input voltages from any two phases  when used in the example showing two phases.

Vx is the voltage at the common point (Cathodes) of the two diodes.
He does not define this (and he should) but you can deduce this from the first pair of equations

[image]

ie Vx = Vinput - voltage drop in inductor due to AC current - diode voltage drop.
This corresponds to starting at Vline and transiting an inductance and a diode. The point in his example that matches this is the DC "bus' where the diode cathodes join.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly ... Vx is actually DC voltage?

Comment: @jurij  Pulsating DC - as gic=ven by the formulae above. As inductior current caries with time the inductor voltage drop will vary and Vx will vary -  see equations above.

Comment: McMahon Could you also explain where is the point when going from first to second equation in your answer (L(line) changes to X(line)?

Comment: Also, forgot to ask ... Vx is pulsating DC in respect to DC ground, right?

Comment: @jurij  You need to look at where all the other "system" voltages are expressed with respect to. Vx(t) is relative to where? Va(t) is relative to ?. The vopltage Vx derived from them is relative to the same point. [[Yes. Ground :-) - but you need to be able to determine that by understanding the circuit and equations.

Comment: @jurij Re the two equations - they are copied from your cited page. Note that the first is dealing with dt and the 2nd with d(wt) . [[omega.t]]